# Plink passing arguments

Tags: c, linux, ssh, plink

```
plink user@10.220.60.xx -t '/home/user/test/testpgm'
```

I'm able to run the below program which resides on a Linux machine from a windows machine using the above plink cmd.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
   int i;
   char buf[30];
   printf("Test Pgm \n");
   printf("No of Arguments=%d\n",argc);
   printf("Enter a string:");
   fflush(stdout);
   gets(buf);
   printf("Input str:%s \n",buf);

   return 0;
}

gcc test.c -o testpgm
```

Question: How to pass command line arguments to this function?
I tried

```
plink user@10.220.60.xx -t '/home/user/test/testpgm arg1'

bash: /home/user/test/testpgm arg1: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The shell treats strings inside quotes as a single word, which means that `plink` tries to execute the program `/home/user/test/testpgm arg1`. Obviously this won't work.

What you have to do is very simple: Skip the quotes!

```
$ plink user@10.220.60.xx -t /home/user/test/testpgm arg1
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried

```
plink user@10.220.60.xx /home/user/test/testpgm arg1
```

Works fine.